# How can I change the whiteBalance gains value in android?

Tags: android, android-camera2, android-camerax

I would like to get the value of the current gains and change the value of the RGB gains.

In iOS, Apple [provides](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1624640-temperatureandtintvaluesfordevic?language=objc) `setWhiteBalanceModeLockedWithDeviceWhiteBalanceGains:completionHandler`.

```
- (void)setWhiteBalanceGains:(AVCaptureWhiteBalanceGains)gains
{
  NSError *error = nil;
  
  if ( [self.captureDevice lockForConfiguration:&error] ) {
    AVCaptureWhiteBalanceGains normalizedGains = [self normalizedGains:gains];
    [self.captureDevice setWhiteBalanceModeLockedWithDeviceWhiteBalanceGains:normalizedGains completionHandler:nil];
    [self.captureDevice unlockForConfiguration];
  }
  else {
    NSLog( @"Could not lock device for configuration: %@", error );
  }
}

- (AVCaptureWhiteBalanceGains)normalizedGains:(AVCaptureWhiteBalanceGains) g
{
  AVCaptureWhiteBalanceGains gains = g;
  gains.redGain = MAX(gains.redGain, 1.0f);
  gains.greenGain = MAX(gains.greenGain, 3.0f);
  gains.blueGain = MAX(gains.blueGain, 18.0f);
  
  return gains;
}
```

How can we achieve this in android using cameraX?

`COLOR_CORRECTION_GAINS`

`COLOR_CORRECTION_MODE`

I have checked in the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest#COLOR_CORRECTION_GAINS) regarding channel control. But how can we change color correction and reset the cameraX preview with the new control?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Camera2Interop`:

```
fun buildPreview() : Preview {
    val builder = Preview.Builder()
    val camera2InterOp = Camera2Interop.Extender(builder)
    camera2InterOp.setCaptureRequestOption(CaptureRequest. COLOR_CORRECTION_MODE, CameraMetadata.COLOR_CORRECTION_MODE_FAST)
    return builder.build()
}
```

Comment: How can we do the color correction with RGB value?

Comment: Does RggbChannelVector  provide the feature you need?

Comment: unable to access `Camera2Interop` class. In which camerax version  is available or any other dependeny need to include?

Comment: currently using alpha version of cameraX.

Comment: I would suggest to upgrade to the latest stable version.

Answer (score 1):

Old but still used is the class Camera.Parameters#getWhiteBalance

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters#getWhiteBalance()

Using class Camera.Parameters call getWhiteBalance.

The newer way is to use Capture request https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest

Here is the full documentation of Camera2
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary